# Casting string/buffer data using swig wrapped typedef structs and enums in python

Tags: python, c, struct, casting, swig

I have some C code that runs on an embedded system, generating a stream of data which my python code will read on the other side of a bluetooth/usb line. The protocol of the stream is still under heavy development, and changes frequently, but is defined in a single .h file. I would like to use SWIG to keep the python side of things up to date, specifically by providing access to the stream data layouts (structs)

Here is a sample .h file describing a number of structures and a few constants (as #defines), obviously a very small subset of the whole protocol, for brevity.

```
//datalayouts.h

#ifdef SWIG
#define __attribute__(x)
#endif

#define TOKEN_TYPE_SYNC_VALUE 1
#define TOKEN_TYPE_DELTA 2

typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    uint8_t token_type;
    uint32_t timestamp;
    uint32_t value;
} struct_token_type_sync_value;

typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    uint8_t token_type;
    int16_t delta;
} struct_token_type_delta;
```

Coupled with this is the basic interface file

```
%module datalayouts
%{
#include "datalayouts.h"
%}
%include "datalayouts.h"
```

It all compiles and imports just fine. In python I can create a variable of type `token_type_sync_value`, but what I want to do is cast a portion of the data I'm reading from the stream (as a string), to impose the correct structure on it.

For example:

```
>>> from datalayouts token_type_sync_value
>>> data = stream.read() #returns 100+ bytes
>>> if ord(data[0]) == TOKEN_TYPE_SYNC_VALUE:
...     #here I want to access data[0:9] as a token_type_sync_value
```

Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with SWIG, the simplest solution is to use `%extend` to supply an extra constructor from within Python that takes a `PyObect` to use as a buffer:

```
%module test

%include <stdint.i>

%inline %{
#ifdef SWIG
#define __attribute__(x)
#endif

#define TOKEN_TYPE_SYNC_VALUE 1
#define TOKEN_TYPE_DELTA 2

typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    uint8_t token_type;
    int16_t delta;
} struct_token_type_delta;
%}

%extend struct_token_type_delta {
  struct_token_type_delta(PyObject *in) {
    assert(PyObject_CheckBuffer(in));
    Py_buffer view;
    const int ret = PyObject_GetBuffer(in, &view, PyBUF_SIMPLE);
    assert(0==ret);
    assert(view.len >= sizeof(struct_token_type_delta));
    struct_token_type_delta *result = new struct_token_type_delta(*static_cast<const struct_token_type_delta*>(view.buf));
    PyBuffer_Release(&view); // Note you could/should retain view.obj for the life of this object to prevent use after free
    return result;
  }
}
```

You'd need to do this for each type you wanted to construct from a buffer, but the actual code for the constructor of each remains the same so could be wrapped as a macro (using `%define`) quite simply. You would also want to do something to prevent the use after free error, by retaining the reference to the underlying buffer for longer.

---

Personally if it were me doing this though I'd look for a different solution, because there are nicer ways of getting the same result and writing code that creates and maintains thin POD/bean like objects is tedious and dull in any language let alone 2 or more. Assuming protbuf is too heavyweight to use in your embedded system I'd look to solve this in reverse, using ctypes for Python and then having your Python code also generate the header for your C build tools as well. So something like:

```
import ctypes

class ProtocolStructure(type(ctypes.Structure)):
  def __str__(self):
    s='''
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
\t%s
}'''
    return s % '\n\t'.join(('%s %s;' % (ty.__name__[2:], name) for name,ty in self._fields_))

class struct_token_type_delta(ctypes.Structure, metaclass=ProtocolStructure):
  _fields_ = (('token_type', ctypes.c_uint8),
              ('delta', ctypes.c_int16))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # when this file is run instead of imported print the header file to stdout

  h='''
#ifndef PROTO_H
#define PROTO_H
%s
#endif
'''

  print(h % ';\n'.join('%s %s;\n' % (ty, name)  for name,ty in globals().items() if issubclass(type(ty), ProtocolStructure)))
```

Which then lets you write:

```
import proto
proto.struct_token_type_delta.from_buffer(bytearray(b'\xff\x11\x22'))
```

Comment: For me the top half of this this answer is more in the direction I am going, and gives me an idea.